# Errors 404 Not Found: The requested address was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying add data into database from admin panel and already created model file, controller and in view folder there is another controller named `neighborhoods` folder where there are two files their names are `index.ctp and add.ctp`

problem when i try to access neighborhoods/index page showing this error

```
Errors 404 Not Found:The requested address '/admin/neighborhoods/index' 
was not found on this server.
```

could you tell me where I'm doing wrong, what is solution of it and how do i access `add.ctp`?

**neighborhood.php model file**

```
class Neighborhood extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Neighborhood';

}
```

**neighborhoods_controller file**

```
class NeighborhoodsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Neighborhoods';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('add','index');

    }


     function index() {
        $this->set('Neighborhoods', $this->Neighborhood->find('all'));
    }

    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->Neighborhood->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your Neighborhood has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you url shown as '/admin/neighborhoods/index' so that admin_index() method call but you didn't create that.

Answer (score 0):

as per your url you have to create admin_index() method for that

```
function admin_index() {
        $this->set('Neighborhoods', $this->Neighborhood->find('all'));
    }
```

just try it out.

Comment: how about `Neighborhood` folder should there `admin_index` name file?

Comment: yes just renamed your file name admin_index.ctp like that.

Comment: i did this method but still same issue

Comment: replace line with this in your beforfilter function $this->Auth->allow('add','admin_index');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116162/discussion-between-kaushal-shah-and-farhan-dharsi).